# SWT treeview - width of the image in the cell

Tags: java, treeview, icons, swt

I want to add an image (size: 36px x 16px) in one cell of a tree viewer.

It works but the image get shrinked to a smaller size as you can see in the following image:

[image: shrinked icon]

The other icons look fine. They are 16px x 16px.

I'm setting the image like this in my custom label provider:

```
@Override
public void update(ViewerCell cell){
   //some code...
   cell.setimage(MyPlugin.getDefault().getImageDescriptor("PATH_TO_ICON").createImage());
}
```

Where can I set the width of the image? Is it possible?

Comment: The screenshot shows three images. How are they set? Do you have multiple columns?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Yes, there are multiple columns (4 to be exact). I just tries to simplify the code... Basically the argument of the setImage() method is a method that return the appropriate image depending on the column.

Comment: Maybe another screenshot that depicts the columns bounds would help. The SWT Table can only display images of the same size (at least on Windows). The first image that is set, dictates the size of all subsequent images. You could try to create and remove a dummy item with the largest image that you know of before proceeding with the _regular_ TabelViewer setup.

Comment: Maybe call `viewer.getTree().setLinesVisible(true)` and then take a screenshot so we can see the boundaries.